# Parse a string in place of expression argument

Tags: r, metaprogramming

I want to send an expression as a parameter to function `list.select` in rlist package.

Normal use of the function `list.select` is as follows:

```
x <- list(p1 = list(type='A',score=list(c1=10,c2=8)), p2 = list(type='B',score=list(c1=9,c2=9)), p3 = list(type='B',score=list(c1=9,c2=7)))
list.select(x, type)
```

`type` is the name of the list element that is selected. I want to parameterize the name of the list element by making it an expression parsed from a string.

```
list.select(x, parse(text='type'))
```

But this doesn't work. Here are the results of both function calls:

```
> list.select(x, type)
$p1
$p1$type
[1] "A"
$p2
$p2$type
[1] "B"
$p3
$p3$type
[1] "B"
> list.select(x, parse(text='type'))
$p1
$p1[[1]]
expression(type)
$p2
$p2[[1]]
expression(type)
$p3
$p3[[1]]
expression(type)
```

How can I use a string in place of the expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.select` does non standard evaluation, so you need to construct the call for it.  Here is an example:

```
tag.name <- "type"
eval(call("list.select", x, as.name(tag.name)))
```

Produces:

```
$p1
$p1$type
[1] "A"


$p2
$p2$type
[1] "B"


$p3
$p3$type
[1] "B"
```

The difference between what I do and what you do is that I construct the entire call to avoid giving `list.select` a chance to interpret its arguments incorrectly.  Your version first evaluates `list.select`, and from that point on you're at the mercy of how `list.select` wants to interpret its arguments.